# jQuery UI Dialog maxHeight gets ignored in IE6

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-6, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following code, in IE6 it ignores the maxHeight.

```
$('.thickbox').click(function(){
    var href = "foo";
    var diaTitle = "bar";

    $("#dialogTest").load(href, function() {
        var container = $(this);
        container.dialog({
            bgiframe: true,
            opacity: false,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 500,
            maxHeight: 550,
            width: 400,
            title: diaTitle,
            modal: true
        })
    });
});
```

Anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: I don't, the client does, it's the only browser they have, this is for an intranet.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post the HTML that is generated by these statements? The CSS property max-height is not supported by Internet Explorer 6, so if Thickbox uses that, it will not work.

Are you sure you need Internet Explorer 6 compatibility?

Comment: `maxHeight` is used as an option of `dialog` plugin and not directly as a css style. It might be doing a hack internally to use something else in IE6.

Comment: 'thickbox' is the class, but I'm not using the thickbox plugin. I'm using the jQuery UI Dialog. IE6 is the only browser the client will use. Big corporation, legacy apps, intranet only sort of deal

Comment: The jQuery UI dialog internally uses the Resizable jQuery UI plugin to handle the sizes, and it doesn't use max-height, so that's not the problem. Now I look into your code a bit further I get confused. The height of the dialog is 500, it is not resizable, and the maximum height is 550? What's the point of maxHeight 550 if the height is 500 and it can't be resized?